# Can I transfer some BTC with 0 tx fee now, when the mempool is empty?

Tags: transaction-fees, mempool, blockspace-market

I wanna send a tiny amount of BTC (0.001BTC). I am not in a hurry and I noticed the mempool is sometimes empty these days because the market is cold. So can I set the network fee to 1sat/byte or even zero?

Will miners add my zero-fee tx to the new block when the mempool is empty?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when the mempool is empty, you can set the transaction fee to the minimum relay fee of 1 sat/vbyte. However you cannot make a transaction no fee as there still is the minimum relay fee. The minimum fee is there to prevent people from spamming 0 fee transactions.